# Handle Null in TypedDataset

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using TypedDataset and exposed it across an asmx service.

**Dataset I have on service side is**
[image]

**Dataset getting generated at client side is**
[image]

You may notice the NullValue(as highlighted), its not the same on both side. And because of this I am getting `StrongTypingException`. Its driving me MAD :(

Comment: What is your question? To handle null values, either check for null before accessing the fields, or set NullValue. But you know that already, right?

Comment: Please show us the error message also why dont you set it to empty or null as default

Comment: My question is , when I have marked it as (Null) in NullValue property at service side, why the same thing is not getting generated at client side.

Comment: @vaibhav Oh, in that case, a web service shouldn't be able to dictate how you handle null values. Not even if it's your own web service, because Visual Studio cannot know that.

Comment: Have you considered creating data transfer objects and mapping the values to that?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value on the client side dataset to also be "(null)". The client and server side datasets generated by the designer are independent things, with their own attribute values